# C++ exporting data to specific excel columns

Tags: c++, csv, xls

I need to output columns of data to consecutive columns in an excel sheet (not bothered if csv etc.).

The program outputs two columns fine, but then I need to iteratively output x number more columns.

eg. `x=50;`
`print << time << '\t' << price1 << endl;`//then also output x = 48 more columns.
`for (x=2; x<=50; x++) { print << '\t'*x << price_x << endl;`}

Comment: If you are printing n columns of the same row then `endl` should not be being used.

Comment: I don't think I am